# Rails 3 object nil or not create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im working on a rails app where a user has the ability to upload photos. When a user uploads their photos it will appear on their profile. Everything works great besides when there is no photos created then I am unable to view the user profile page because of the photo being nil.

here is my show method in the users_controller.rb

```
def show 
@user = User.find_by_id(:id)
@photo = @user.photos.find(params[:id])
end
```

Here is my show.html.erb

```
 <% for photo in @user.photos %>
  <%= photo.title %>
  <%= photo.description %>
  <%= image_tag photo.image_url(:thumbnail) %>
  <%= link_to "Show", photo %>
 <br>
 <% end %>
```

How can I bypass this error?

Comment: `User.find_by_id(:id)` looks... wrong. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Find a user by the user_id of the profile. I am a rails noob and this is my first project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for your action seems wrong...

It should be this:

```
def show 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  #@photo = @user.photos.find(params[:id])
end
```

I commented out the third line on purpose, because I'm not sure what it is you want to do there, yet.

The `@user` variable needs to be defined using `params[:id]`, given that this is the `show` action for the `UsersController`, so the id for the user will be passed through as `params[:id]`.

But then you go and use this to find the photo for the user, which is what confuses me... the `Photo` record's `id` attribute is probably not going to be the same as the `User` record's `id` attribute.

So what is it?

Comment: I figured by adding `@photo = @user.photos.find(params[:id])` I could show the photos view on the users show page. The code you have posted above that is the code I changed out. Also it worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the code in your `show.html.erb` with this:

```
<% if @user.photos %>
<% for photo in @user.photos %>
  <%= photo.title %>
  <%= photo.description %>
  <%= image_tag photo.image_url(:thumbnail) %>
  <%= link_to "Show", photo %>
  <br>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is, when the user doesn't have any photos, `@user.photos` returns `nil` so you have to check for that first.

Comment: How does the above code differentiate from the code originally posted?

Comment: I have added an `if` condition.